# joomla 2.5 get seo link by article id

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, seo, article

let´s say I have following id´s from articles (#__content)

3,4,5 and I want to know the SEO URLs for these ID´s within my template.

pseudo code:

```
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $db->setQuery($query);

 $query
        ->select(array('a.seolink'))
        ->from('#__content AS a')
        ->where("a.id = '3'" );
```

Anyone knows a query or function which does the job?

with kind regards,

tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have article slug (`"id:alias"`) and category slug (`"catid:catalias"`), then you could do

```
$link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($slug, $catslug));
```

From `#__content` you can get `id`, `alias` and `catid`, so you just have to get category alias too (since I think it won't work without it, but you can try)

Offtopic: anyone interested in adding tag synonyms for Joomla, [please give your opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173293/tag-synonyms-for-joomla)

Comment: and it works also without catalias ; 
f.e.
$slug = "3:Kontakt"; 
$catslug = "8";